# TestNG Test Case failing with JMockit "Invalid context for the recording of expectations"

Tags: maven-2, maven, maven-3, testng, jmockit

The following TestNG (6.3) test case generates the error "Invalid context for the recording of expectations"

```
@Listeners({ Initializer.class })
public final class ClassUnderTestTest {

private ClassUnderTest cut;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@BeforeMethod
private void initialise() {
    cut = new ClassUnderTest();
}

@Test
public void doSomething() {
    new Expectations() {
        MockedClass tmc;
        {
            tmc.doMethod("Hello"); result = "Hello";
        }
    };
    String result = cut.doSomething();
    assertEquals(result, "Hello");
}
```

}

The class under test is below.

```
public class ClassUnderTest {

MockedClass service = new MockedClass();
MockedInterface ifce = new MockedInterfaceImpl();

public String doSomething() {
    return (String) service.doMethod("Hello");
}

public String doSomethingElse() {
    return (String) ifce.testMethod("Hello again");
}
}
```

I am making the assumption that because I am using the @Listeners annotation that I do not require the javaagent command line argument.  This assumption may be wrong....

Can anyone point out what I have missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JMockit-TestNG `Initializer` must run once for the whole test run, so using `@Listeners` on individual test classes won't work.

Instead, simply upgrade to JMockit 0.999.11, which works transparently with TestNG 6.2+, without any need to specify a listener or the `-javaagent` parameter (unless running on JDK 1.5).

Comment: Thanks, just the version update sorted the issue.  Take you point about Listeners.  Thanks for the info.